# How to create a nested table in an object-relational database using Schema Builder in Laravel?

Tags: database, postgresql, laravel, object-relational-model, laravel-schema-builder

I have an object-relational database that has table 'software' with a nested table named 'installations'.

I am used to using Schema Builder with relational databases, and describing my columns this way:

`$table->integer('column_name');`

Now, how can I describe the nested table type to the schema builder

I'd imagine it to be something like this:

`$table->nestedTable('my_nested_table')->withColums('nested_table_column_1', ..);`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with all PostgreSQL features, but I don't think you can do that with the Schema Builder. Keep in mind that the Schema Builder is database agnostic, so it only offers features that are are common to all RDBMSs it supports. If this requires some special syntax that is specific to PostgreSQL, then that will most likely not be something abstracted by the builder and you'd end up using `DB::statement` with raw queries. The [Migration Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations) enumerates nicely what you can do with it, so I suggest you read that.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of the DB:statement and what I can do with it, but I was asking whether there was a built-in solution that handles what I am asking for. Anyway, I'll read more, thank you.